# Proving inequality with constraint $abc=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

For positive reals $a,b,c$, with $abc=1$, prove that $$\frac{a^3+1}{b^2+1}+ \frac{b^3+1}{c^2+1}+\frac{c^3+1}{a^2+1} \geq 3$$ I tried the substitution $x/y,y/z,z/x$, but it didn't give me anything. What else to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By re-arrangement inequality, we have 
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{a^3+1}{b^2+1} \ge \sum_{cyc} \frac{a^3+1}{a^2+1}$$

So it is enough to show that for positive $x$, the function
$$f(x) = \frac{x^3+1}{x^2+1}-1-\frac12 \log x \ge 0$$
as the inequality is equivalent to $f(a)+f(b)+f(c) \ge 0$.

From $\displaystyle f'(x) = (x-1)\frac{2x^4 + x^3 + 7x^2 + x + 1}{2x (x^2+1)^2}$, it is clear that
$f$ is decreasing for $x \in (0, 1)$ and increasing for $x > 1$.

Now as $f(1) = 0$, we must have $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x > 0$.

Comment: Great. But is there a solution from AM-GM or Cauchy-Schwarz... It's just because I am really comfortable with them. Please ,if you find one, please share. Thanks.

Comment: OK, here is another way to complete after the rearrangement.  Show that $$\frac{a^3+1}{a^2+1} \ge \frac{a+1}2 \iff (a+1)(a-1)^2 \ge 0$$  Now you should be able to use AM-GM to show $a+b+c \ge 3$ to conclude.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you asked me to **show**

Comment: Can you please post a complete solution. I am having a really hard time following you.

Comment: OK, here is the alternate approach to show $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \frac{a^3+1}{a^2+1} \ge \sum_{cyc} \frac{a+1}2 \ge 3$:  
Note $2(a^3+1)\ge (a^2+1)(a+1)$ is equivalent to $a^3-a^2-a+1 \ge 0$, which is in turn equivalent to $(a+1)(a-1)^2 \ge 0$.  

Hence we have $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \frac{a^3+1}{a^2+1} \ge \sum_{cyc} \frac{a+1}2 = \frac32+\frac12(a+b+c)$.  But $a+b+c \ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}=3$, so we have the inequality.

Comment: @Macavity: This alternate approach would also work if you use AM-GM *instead* of the rearrangement inequality, because then for each factor $(a^3+1)/(a^2+1) \ge (a+1)/2 \ge \sqrt a$.

Comment: Wait, how would it work without Rearrangement inequality?

Answer (score 4):

There is already a full and great answer. This is only an alternative
using AM-GM instead of the rearrangement inequality:

From the AM-GM inequality we have
$$
\frac 13 \left(\frac{a^3+1}{b^2+1}+ \frac{b^3+1}{c^2+1}+\frac{c^3+1}{a^2+1} \right) \ge
 \left(\frac{a^3+1}{b^2+1} \cdot \frac{b^3+1}{c^2+1} \cdot \frac{c^3+1}{a^2+1} \right)^{1/3}
$$
therefore it suffices to show that
$$
\frac{a^3+1}{a^2+1} \cdot \frac{b^3+1}{b^2+1} \cdot \frac{c^3+1}{c^2+1} 
\ge 1 \, .
$$
From 
$$
 0 \le (a^2 - 1)(a-1) = 2(a^3 +1) - (a^2+1)(a+1)
$$
it follows that
$$
 \frac {a^3+1}{a^2+1} \ge \frac{a+1}{2} \, ,
$$
this is the crucial estimate given by Macavity in the comment [Proving inequality with constraint $abc=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552926/proving-inequality-with-constraint-abc-1/1553379#comment3162228_1553017) above.
We continue with
$$
 \frac{a+1}{2} \ge \sqrt{1 \cdot a} = \sqrt a \,
$$
using AM-GM again.

The same holds for $b$ and $c$, this gives
$$
\frac{a^3+1}{a^2+1} \cdot \frac{b^3+1}{b^2+1} \cdot \frac{c^3+1}{c^2+1}
\ge \sqrt {abc} = 1 \, .
$$